# Best practice for parsing data of mixed type?

Tags: c, parsing

I am wondering whether there is any known best practice/method for parsing mixed type of data packet.

For instance, let's say the data is 10 bytes, and it consists of:

Byte 0-1: manufacturer ID (int)
Byte 2:   type (int)
Byte 3-4: device id (ascii char)

I could simply define each data type size and location as #define, and parse it using those defines. But I am wondering if there is any structure to organise this better.

Comment: is the data binary or text?

Comment: If you know the packet definition ahead of time, why not just define a custom struct with all of the required fields?

Comment: You have to read the data just like how you wrote it... Since it looks like it is a binary file...

Comment: Does data pass though files for other platforms? Post some sample inputs and exported output data packets.  Else this is too broad/unclear.

Comment: "*Byte 0-4*" is 5 bytes... and the data should be **10 bytes**...?

Comment: @Ruks maybe its very, very big bytes \*duck-'n-run\*

Comment: "data is 10 bytes" --> How are the reaming 5 byte defined?

Comment: @Jinsuk, "I could simply define each data type size and location as #define, and parse it using those defines" --> I truly wish you had done that, posted that code and then asked about best practices.  It would add information and make for a good post. This one is too broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best practice it to assume all data from outside the program (e.g. from the user, from a file, from a network, from a different process) is potentially incorrect (and potentially unsafe/malicious).

Then, based on the assumption of "potential incorrectness" define types to distinguish between "unchecked, potential incorrect data" and "checked, known correct data". For your example, you could use `uint8_t packet[10];` as the data type for unchecked data and a normal structure (with padding and without `__attribute__((packed));`) for the checked data. This makes it extremely difficult for a programmer to accidentally use unsafe data when they think they're using safe/checked data.

Of course you will also need code to convert between these data types, which needs to do as many sanity checks as possible (and possibly also worry about things like endianess). For your example these checks could be:

- are any of the bytes that are supposed to be ASCII characters >= 0x80, and are any of them invalid (e.g. maybe control characters like backspace are not permitted).
- is the manufacturer ID valid (e.g. maybe there's an enumeration that it needs to match)
- is the type valid (e.g. maybe there's an enumeration that it needs to match)

Note that this function should return some kind of status to indicate if the conversion was successful or not, and in most cases this status should also give an indication of what the problem was if the conversion wasn't successful (so that the caller can inform the user or log the problem or handle the problem in the most suitable way for the problem). For example, maybe "unknown manufacturer ID" means that the program needs to be updated to handle a new manufacturer and that the data was correct, and "invalid manufacturer ID" means that the data was definitely wrong.

Comment: Haha I saw `__attribute__((packed))` and instinctively downvoted - well, reversed now.

Comment: but perhaps use `uint8_t` for input.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: Fixed `uint8_t` :-)

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
struct packet {
    uint16_t mfg;
    uint8_t type;
    uint16_t devid;
} __attribute__((packed));
```

The packed attribute (or your platform's equivalent) is required to avoid implicit padding which doesn't exist in the protocol.

Once you have the above struct, you simply cast (part of) a char array which you received from wherever:

```
char buf[1000];
(struct packet*)(buf + N);
```

Comment: [Usual suspects](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vtSmfws0_To): A complaint C complier may not have any packing ability.  Should the packet come from another machine, endian may differ.

Comment: Yea. like this :) ...@chux, Presumably if you know the data packet definition, you know what endianness it uses as well. If you need to, you can do your bit/byte-swapping before casting with the struct.

Comment: Also, `packed` is a sure way to cause undefined behaviour in even those compilers that support packing. Casting an array of char to a packet is a violation of strict aliasing rule.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: I did not cast an array of char.  I cast `buf + N` which is a char*.  Which to my understanding is allowed to be cast (there's an exception to strict aliasing for char*).  What do you think about that?

Comment: The strict aliasing for `char *` yes, but it is the opposite direction. It says that you can access bytes of any object as character type. It does not say that you can access the elements of an array of character as any object type.

Answer (score 0):

For a fully portable version, I suggest you do the read in this fashion:

```
    struct {
        uint16_t e1;
        uint8_t e2;
        uint16_t e3;
    } d;

    uint8_t *cursor;
    uint8_t rbuf[5];

    read(sock, rbuf, sizeof(rbuf));
    memcpy(&s.e1, &rbuf[0], sizeof(s.e1));
    s.e2 = rbuf[2];
    memcpy(&s.e3, &rbuf[3], sizeof(s.e3));

    s.e1 = ntohs(s.e1);
    s.e3 = ntohs(s.e3);
```

You may be tempted to do something like others answers said, something like:

```
    struct s {
        uint16_t e1;
        uint8_t e2;
        uint16_t e3;
    } __attribute__((packed));

    struct s d;
    read(sock, &d, sizeof(d));
    s.e1 = ntohs(s.e1);
    s.e3 = ntohs(s.e3);
```

However, this code is not fully portable and can lead you to problems, since you are accessing items (`s.e3`) with unaligned memory, which is in itself undefined behavior. Under some circumstances, this fashion OK and desirable (less cache polluting since more structs can fill the different cache lines, and maybe simpler code), but in others cases, it can cause a bus error and make your code incompatible for some architectures.

Beyond that, you should follow other best practices, like trying to read as many structs at possible between `read()` calls, make nicer code about net-to-host byte-ordering translations... but I think that avoid the non-standard attribute should be the first thing.

Note that if you DON'T do unaligned access, all of this (even the `__packed__` attribute) is completely unnecesary, and that you can read the structs like:

```
struct {
    uint16_t e1;
    uint8_t e2;
    uint8_t e2;
    uint16_t e3;
} d;

read(rsock, &d, sizeof(d));
```